# RecursionError when calling pickeled function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I am trying to run the following code:

```
import pickle

def foo():
    print("i am foo")
    
pickle_foo = pickle.dumps(foo)

def foo():
    print("i am the new foo")
    fkt = pickle.loads(pickle_foo)
    return fkt()

foo()
```

The expected behavior would be:

- the new defined function "foo" is called
- in the new function the old function gets unpickeled and then called

  output:

```
i am the new foo
i am foo
```

What actually happens is:

- the new function foo gets called, and then recursively calls itself until a Recursion Error gets thrown:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

The error does not occur, when the two functions are named differently, but that would be very unpractical for my project.
Could anyone explain, why this behavior occurs and how to avoid it (without changing the function names)?

Comment: I dont use pickle (so I may be wrong) but it looks like you are calling `pickle_foo` after you call the second `foo` function. That means in order to actually delete the first `foo` you have to put it outside the second `foo`

Answer (score 3):

The `pickle` module pickles functions based on their fully-qualified name reference. This means that if your function is redefined somewhere in code, and then you unpickle a pickled reference to it, calling it will result in a call to the new definition.

From the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) on `pickle`:

> Note that functions (built-in and user-defined) are pickled by “fully
> qualified” name reference, not by value. 2 This means that only the
> function name is pickled, along with the name of the module the
> function is defined in. Neither the function’s code, nor any of its
> function attributes are pickled. Thus the defining module must be
> importable in the unpickling environment, and the module must contain
> the named object, otherwise an exception will be raised.

What you can do however, is use `inspect.getsource()` to retrieve the source code for your function, and pickle that. This requires that your code be available as source somewhere on the file system, so compiled C code imported, or other outside sources (interpreter input, dynamically loaded modules) will not work.

When you unpickle it, you can use `exec` to convert it into a function and execute it.

Note: this will redefine `foo` every time, so calls to `foo` cannot be guaranteed to have the same effect.

Note 2: `exec` is unsafe and usually unsuitable for code that will be interacting with external sources. Make sure you protect calls to `exec` from potential external attacks that attempt to execute arbitrary code.